# Pipelist names on Windows

Tags: c#

How to get a pipelist with C#? I know about the next trick:

```
Directory.GetFile(@"\\.\\pipe\")
```

but I want to get number of instances of each pipe. I've got a code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace PipeList {
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
  internal struct LARGE_INTEGER {
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal Int64  QuadPart;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal Int32  LowPart;
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    internal UInt32 HighPart;
  } //LARGE_INTEGER

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  internal struct IO_STATUS_BLOCK {
    internal UInt32 Status;
    internal UInt64 Information;
  } //IO_STATUS_BLOCK

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  internal struct FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION {
    internal UInt32        NextEntryOffset;
    internal UInt32        FileIndex;
    internal LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
    internal LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
    internal LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
    internal LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;
    internal LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;
    internal LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;
    internal UInt32        FileAttributes;
    internal UInt32        FileNameLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    internal Byte[]        FileName;
  } //FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION

  internal static class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        String    lpFileName,
        UInt32    dwDesiredAccess,
        FileShare dwShareMode,
        IntPtr    lpSecurityAttributes,
        FileMode  dwCreationDisposition,
        UInt32    dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr    hTemplateFile
    );

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 NtQueryDirectoryFile(
        SafeFileHandle      FileHandle,
        IntPtr              Event,
        IntPtr              ApcRoutine,
        IntPtr              ApcContext,
        out IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
        [Out] IntPtr        FileInformation,
        UInt32              Length,
        UInt32              FileInformationClass,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        Boolean             ReturnSingleEntry,
        IntPtr              FileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        Boolean             RestartScan
    );
  } //NativeMethods

  internal sealed class Program {
    const UInt32 FileDirectoryInformation = 1;
    const UInt32 GENERIC_READ   = 0x80000000;
    const Int32  STATUS_SUCCESS = 0x00000000;

    static T PtrToStruct<T>(IntPtr p) {
      return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(T));
    }

    static void GetLastError() {
      Console.WriteLine(new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
    }

    static void Main() {
      SafeFileHandle pipes;
      IntPtr ptr, ofs;
      IO_STATUS_BLOCK isb;
      Int32 ntstatus;
      Boolean query = true;

      pipes = NativeMethods.CreateFile(
        @"\\.\pipe\", GENERIC_READ, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete,
        IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero
      );

      if (pipes.IsInvalid) {
        GetLastError();
        return;
      }

      Console.WriteLine("{0,-40}{1,14}{2,20}", "Pipe Name", "Instances", "Max Instances");
      Console.WriteLine("{0,-40}{1,14}{2,20}", "---------", "---------", "-------------");

      ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION)));
      try {
        ofs = ptr;
        while (true) {
          ntstatus = NativeMethods.NtQueryDirectoryFile(
            pipes, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out isb, ofs, 1024,
            FileDirectoryInformation, false, IntPtr.Zero, query
          );

          if (ntstatus != STATUS_SUCCESS) break;

          while (true) {
            FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION fdi = PtrToStruct<FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION>(ofs);
            IntPtr name = (IntPtr)(
              Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION), "FileName").ToInt64() + ofs.ToInt64()
            );
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-40}{1,14}{2,20}",
              Marshal.PtrToStringUni(name, (Int32)(fdi.FileNameLength / 2)),
              fdi.EndOfFile.LowPart,
              fdi.AllocationSize.LowPart
            );

            if (fdi.NextEntryOffset == 0) break;
            ofs = (IntPtr)(ofs.ToInt64() + fdi.NextEntryOffset);
          } //while
          query = false;
        } //while
      }
      catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
      finally {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
      }

      pipes.Close();
    }
  } //Program
}
```

but it works well only on CLR 2. Could someone explain me an issue of a code above? Why it does not correctly work on CLR 4?

Comment: OK, mdbg said that there is OutOfmemoryException. So, maybe someone knows how to fix this issue?